# How to get tuya bluetooth devices with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bluetooth, tuya

I used this module

https://pypi.org/project/tinytuya/

to work with my wifi tuya devices.

Recently, I added a bluetooth device (temperature & humidity sensor) that works well on my androïd app smartlife and did not found a module.

I tried the following script from [Method "DefaultAdapter" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Manager" doesn't exist in raspberry pi 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898476/method-defaultadapter-with-signature-on-interface-org-bluez-manager-doesn)

But did not get any device.

Any idea why this script does not work? How to deal with tuya bluetooth devices?

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus() 

SERVICE_NAME = "org.bluez"
OBJECT_IFACE =  "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager"
ADAPTER_IFACE = SERVICE_NAME + ".Adapter1"
DEVICE_IFACE = SERVICE_NAME + ".Device1"
PROPERTIES_IFACE = "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"
manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"), "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager")
objects = manager.GetManagedObjects()
for path, ifaces in objects.items():
    adapter = ifaces.get(ADAPTER_IFACE)
    if adapter is None:
        continue
    obj = bus.get_object(SERVICE_NAME, path)
    adapter = dbus.Interface(obj, ADAPTER_IFACE)
```

bluetoothctl show

```
Controller 00:08:CA:F1:65:CD (public)
    Name: Artens
    Alias: Artens
    Class: 0x005c010c
    Powered: yes
    PowerState: on
    Discoverable: no
    DiscoverableTimeout: 0x000000b4
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: SIM Access                (0000112d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Notification Se.. (00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: IrMC Sync                 (00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0542
    Discovering: no
```

script2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/bluezutils.py

# SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1-or-later

import dbus

SERVICE_NAME = "org.bluez"
ADAPTER_INTERFACE = SERVICE_NAME + ".Adapter1"
DEVICE_INTERFACE = SERVICE_NAME + ".Device1"

def get_managed_objects():
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"),
                "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager")
    return manager.GetManagedObjects()

def find_adapter(pattern=None):
    return find_adapter_in_objects(get_managed_objects(), pattern)

def find_adapter_in_objects(objects, pattern=None):
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    for path, ifaces in objects.items():
        adapter = ifaces.get(ADAPTER_INTERFACE)
        if adapter is None:
            continue
        if not pattern or pattern == adapter["Address"] or \
                            path.endswith(pattern):
            obj = bus.get_object(SERVICE_NAME, path)
            return dbus.Interface(obj, ADAPTER_INTERFACE)
    raise Exception("Bluetooth adapter not found")

def find_device(device_address, adapter_pattern=None):
    return find_device_in_objects(get_managed_objects(), device_address,
                                adapter_pattern)

def find_device_in_objects(objects, device_address, adapter_pattern=None):
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    path_prefix = ""
    if adapter_pattern:
        adapter = find_adapter_in_objects(objects, adapter_pattern)
        path_prefix = adapter.object_path
    for path, ifaces in objects.items():
        device = ifaces.get(DEVICE_INTERFACE)
        if device is None:
            continue
        if (device["Address"] == device_address and
                        path.startswith(path_prefix)):
            obj = bus.get_object(SERVICE_NAME, path)
            return dbus.Interface(obj, DEVICE_INTERFACE)

    raise Exception("Bluetooth device not found")

print("Start")
get_managed_objects
find_adapter
find_device('hci0')
print("End")
```

Comment: Take a look at the examples in the official BlueZ repo https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/bluezutils.py . It is attempting to find the first Bluetooth adapter on your Linux system. In the terminal use `bluetoothctl show` to see what that finds as the adapter as that tool is using the same API

Comment: Thanks @ukBaz, I'll try and let you know. At a first quick look, it's close to my try ...

Comment: I tried and this new script does not return the device too :-(

Comment: And what did `bluetoothctl show` return?

Comment: `bluetoothctl` is reporting you have an adapter so that isn't the problem. I suspect it is your Python setup. Are you using a Python Virtual Environment (e.g. a `venv`)?

Comment: Yes I'am using venv. I'll try to do it directly.

Comment: No change. I updated my post with 'you' script to be sure there is no misunderstanding. Specially because I had to enter bluetooth connector address in this script and not in my first one. I'll try to understand why, I appreciate if you can review the code also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256625/discussion-between-ukbaz-and-dri372).

Comment: Hello again @ukBaz. THANKS for your help with the caht. I saw the device with nFR Connect. Does this mean that since it's a BLE device, it cannot be discovered from my laptop bluetooth?